# Copy File from document library to another with PowerShell CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm trying to copy documents from a document library in staging environment to a document library in the preproduction environment using PowerShell CSOM. The code I've tested is as follows:

```
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$loadInfo3 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO")

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

# Paramètres du script
$orgSiteUrl = "http://site1/"
$destSiteUrl = "http://site2/"
$orgLibrary = "Documents"
$destLibrary = "Documents"
$srcLibrary = $web.Lists["Documents"] 
$destLibrary = $destWeb.Lists["Documents"] 

$orgClientContext = $null
$destClientContext = $null

function MoveFiles(
    [string]$orgSiteUrl,
    [string]$destSiteUrl,
    [string]$orgLibrary,
    [string]$destLibrary
)
{

    $UserName = 'someDomain\someUser'
    $SecurePassword = "somePassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

    Write-Host "Script running with following account : "$UserName -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
    $ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($orgSiteUrl)
    $destClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($destSiteUrl)

    # Connect to source site
    $credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    $ClientContext.Credentials = $credentials
    $web = $ClientContext.Web
    $ClientContext.Load($web)
    $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    # Connect to destination site
    $credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    $destClientContext.Credentials = $credentials
    $destWeb = $destClientContext.Web
    $destClientContext.Load($destWeb)
    $destClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    # Get List and List Items
    $List = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($orgLibrary)
    $ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
    $ClientContext.Load($List)
    $ClientContext.Load($ListItems)
    $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    # Get List and List Items
    $destList = $destWeb.Lists.GetByTitle($destLibrary)
    $destClientContext.Load($destList)
    $destClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    For ($j=0; $j -lt $ListItems.Count; $j++){

        $item = $ListItems[$j]
        $ClientContext.Load($item) 
        $file = $item.File       
        $ClientContext.Load($file)
        $binaryStream = $file.OpenBinaryStream()
        $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
        $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
        $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $binaryStream
        $FileCreationInfo.URL = $destList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $item.File.Name
        $Upload = $destList.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
        $destClientContext.Load($Upload)
        $destClientContext.ExecuteQuery()   

    }

}

MoveFiles -orgSiteUrl $orgSiteUrl -destSiteUrl $destSiteUrl -orgLibrary $orgLibrary -destLibrary $destLibrary -UserName $UserName -SecurePassword $SecurePassword
```

The problem appears when the script is trying to add the binary stream to the FileInfoCreation object in the following line :

```
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $binaryStream
```

The error is as follows :

```
Exception setting "ContentStream": "Cannot convert the 
"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult`1[System.IO.Stream]" value of type 
"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult`1[[System.IO.Stream, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]" to type "System.IO.Stream"."
At D:\Users\Rteetnous-int-setup\Desktop\MoveFileCSOM.ps1:77 char:9
+         $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $binaryStream
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "parameters.Content, 
parameters.ContentStream
Nom du paramètre: La valeur spécifiée n'est pas prise en charge pour le paramètre 
parameters.Content, parameters.ContentStream."
At D:\Users\Rteetnous-int-setup\Desktop\MoveFileCSOM.ps1:81 char:9
+         $destClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

It's obvious that it's a cast error, but I searched and googled for hours and found nothing.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this or suggest another solution using client side scripting ?

Thanks.

Comment: Another way that I found is to download the document and upload it into the target library, but the same issue appears when it's about dealing with object type, but this could be a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it myself, just use:

`$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $binaryStream.Value`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use the native [file.copyto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.copyto.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method. It is straight forward to use but let me know if you need an example.

Yeah I can't read. I changed your script a bit:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$orgSiteUrl = "http://sitea"
$destSiteUrl = "http://siteb"
$orgLibrary = "Documents"
$destLibrary = "More Documents"

function Move-Files{
[cmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$orgSiteUrl,
        [string]$destSiteUrl,
        [string]$orgLibrary,
        [string]$destLibrary,
        [string]$userName,
        [string]$password
    )
    $securePassword = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    Write-Warning "Script running with following account: $userName"
    # Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
    $sctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($orgSiteUrl)
    $dctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($destSiteUrl)
    # Connect to source site
    $credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $securePassword)
    $sctx.Credentials = $credentials
    $srcList = $sctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($orgLibrary)
    $srcItems = $srcList.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
    $sctx.Load($srcList)
    $sctx.Load($srcItems)
    $sctx.ExecuteQuery()
    # Connect to destination site
    $credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    $dctx.Credentials = $credentials
    $destList = $dctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($destLibrary)
    $rootFolder = $destList.RootFolder
    $destItems = $destlist.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
    $dctx.Load($rootFolder)
    $dctx.Load($destList)
    $dctx.Load($destItems)
    $dctx.ExecuteQuery()
    For ($j=0; $j -lt $srcItems.Count; $j++){
        $item = $srcItems[$j]
        $sctx.Load($item) 
        $file = $item.File       
        $sctx.Load($file)
        $sctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($sctx, $item.File.ServerRelativeUrl)
        $destUrl = $destList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $item.File.Name
        Write-Verbose "Adding $destUrl"
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::SaveBinaryDirect($dctx, $destUrl, $fileinfo.Stream, $true) | Out-Null
    }
}
Move-Files -orgSiteUrl $orgSiteUrl -destSiteUrl $destSiteUrl -orgLibrary $orgLibrary -destLibrary $destLibrary -userName "domain\user" -password "Password" -Verbose
```

Comment: I don't think that it will work for 2 different SharePoint farms. Did you tried it ?

Comment: See my edit for updated details.